# Conditional html element only displaying temporarily

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

New to angular, so I'm possible missing something basic here. I have a app component that runs a test on data stored in local storage and then displays the results. The results are conditionally displayed based on a boolean variable set during the function performed when you run the test. However, the results are displaying for a second a most then disappearing.

I have tried removing the conditional, results still only flash. My guess is then  that the test results (stored in a variable) are themselves reset when the page auto reloads. However disabling the auto reloading when using ng serve does not solve the problem.

Relevant code below.

html of app component:

```
<div>
    <form id='chiSquareForm'>
        <label for='dieType'>Die Type:</label>
        <div *ngFor="let dieType of dieTypes">
            <input type="radio" name="dieType" value="{{dieType}}" (change)="dieTypeChangeHandler($event)"><i>{{dieType}}</i>
        </div>
        <button (click) = "runChiSquare()">Run Test</button>
    </form>
</div>>
<div *ngIf = "displayResults">
    <h1>Results</h1>
    <p>{{testResults}}</p>
</div>
```

and relevant component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chi-square-form',
  templateUrl: './chi-square-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chi-square-form.component.css']
})
export class ChiSquareFormComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedDieType: string = '';

  testResults = '';

  displayResults;

  //create critical value table (only including degrees of freedom for dice, and probability of .95
  criticalValues = {
    3: 7.815,
    5: 11.070,
    7: 14.067,
    9: 16.919,
    19: 30.144
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  runChiSquare() {

    //set displayResults to true to show conditional HTML 
    
    this.displayResults = true;

    
    //some code to calculate chi
    
    
    //check chi against critical value
    
      let criticalValue = this.criticalValues[degreesOfFreedom];
    
      let fair = true;
      if (chi > criticalValue) {
      fair = false
      }
      if (fair === false) {
      output = "Your die is so not fucking fair!";
      } else {
      output ="Your die is fair, blame something else!"
    }
}
  this.testResults = output;
    return output;
    };
}
```

Comment: apparently your code looks ok, (apart from you don't have mentioned datatypes for your variables e.g. displayResults should be public displayResults:boolean = false)

Make sure you don't have any error in the console

Comment: I have no errors in the console, thanks!